# Javascript Вывод даты

Tags: javascript

В `data1[0].date` находится дата/время: `2017-10-10 12:10:44`
Как вывести только дату: `2017-10-10`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дарю:

```js
Date.prototype.format = function(format = 'yyyy-mm-dd') {
    if (this.toString() === 'Invalid Date') {
        return;
    }
    const replaces = {
        yyyy: this.getFullYear(),
        mm: ('0' + (this.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
        dd: ('0' + this.getDate()).slice(-2),
        hh: ('0' + this.getHours()).slice(-2),
        MM: ('0' + this.getMinutes()).slice(-2),
        ss: ('0' + this.getSeconds()).slice(-2)
    };
    let result = format;
    for (const replace in replaces) {
        result = result.replace(replace, replaces[replace]);
    }
    return result;
};

console.log(new Date().format())
console.log(new Date().format('dd/mm/yyyy hh.MM.ss'))
```

Хотя в ващем случае можно обойтись этим:

```js
const date = '2017-10-10 12:10:44';
console.log(date.split(' ')[0]);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Второй вариант удобнее

Comment: Может все же правильный ответ человеку дадите? А то он так и будет с датой, как со строкой работать...

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko так у него это и так строка. Смысл парсить её в дату и потом собирать из нее обратно год месяц и день, если можно её просто обрезать? Если вы знаете какой-то более правильный ответ - дайте его сами

Comment: Я думаю, @ВалерийОрлов этот ответ понравился и бог с ним. Чему-то научился он из него? Работать с датой? Нет, не думаю.