# Javascript. Формат времени

Tags: javascript, время

Добрый день.
Бьюсь, не могу отобразить время в нужном формате:
Нужно так - `2018-01-05T21:02:46.167030+02:00`
Именно с такой последовательностью, с такими символами. Почему-то форматировать правильно не віходит.

Вот до чего дошел ( это без попыток форматировать, т.к. они ужасны ):

```
var date = new Date().toString().replace(/\s+/g,'').replace('(FLEStandardTime)', '');
```

Буду крайне благодарен, если поможете

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Javascript Вывод даты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/728900/javascript-%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b)

Comment: А вот это после точки и до плюса:  .167030+ что?

Comment: @VladVetrov я так понимаю временной пояс

Comment: @Darth нет, не совсем

Comment: @VladVetrov похоже на микросекунды

Comment: Вам обязательно именно микросекунды и именно часовой пояс? Возможно, вам нужен просто формат ISO 8601 — его возвращает `new Date().toISOString()`. Если же вам нужны микросекунды и часовой пояс, не могли бы вы рассказать, зачем?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var date = new Date();
date.toISOString();
```

Необходимо доработать, чтоб окончание было таким как вам надо. Надо было изменить на стандарт ISO.

Также многие для простоты использования юзают [Moment.JS](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: да, спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 2):

Может вам попробовать использовать moment.js https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/227011)

Comment: @andreymal, название библиотеки не является ответом-ссылкой.

Comment: @Qwertiy по ссылке находится код, который является ответом на вопрос. Вопрос — вывести дату в нужном формате, а не найти библиотеку для этого. Название библиотеки хоть со ссылкой, хоть без — не является ответом на вопрос

Comment: @andreymal, ну да, было бы хорошо добавить конкретный пример, как получить нужный формат. Тем не менее, я считаю, что это ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy не хорошо бы, а обязательно бы